# How to make a google sheets function reference the cell it was called from

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

#### background

I followed [this tutorial](http://igoogledrive.blogspot.com/2013/06/google-spreadsheet-navigate-to-another.html) which basically makes a button call a google sheets script like this

```
function jumpToDetail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("details");
  ss.setActiveSheet(sheet).setActiveSelection("A2");
}
```

that makes you jump to a specific cell. I looked at the google sheets [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) but couldn't figure out how to make this function *reference* the cell it was called from

#### question

How do I make a function in google sheets reference the function it was called from. For example I would like the final code to look something like this:

```
function jumpToDetail(clickedCell) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("details");
  // get the value of "id" of the same row the cell was clicked in
  ss.setActiveSheet(sheet).setActiveSelection(function_of(id));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The active range is obtained with `getActiveRange` method of `SpreadsheetApp`. This can be useful when a script is called from a custom function:  the active range is then the cell at which the custom function is located.  Example:

```
function currentCell() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
}
```

Entering `=currentcell()` anywhere in the sheet will return the A1 notation of that cell.

But clicking a button (an inserted drawing) has no effect on active range, because drawings are not associated with any cell in a sheet. They are in their own layer, floating over the sheet. In a script called with a button, the active range is wherever the selected cell(s) happen to be, and has nothing to do with the location of the button.

In order to communicate some location to a script, the user would have to select a cell first and then call a script (via a button or a menu).

Here is a function that returns the content of the cell in the current row with column labeled "id". (The label is assumed to be in the 1st row of the sheet.)

```
function getId() {
  var row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var column = headers[0].indexOf('id') + 1;
  if (column > 0) {
    return sheet.getRange(row, column).getValue();
  }
  else {
    throw new Error('No column labeled id');
  }
}
```

Comment: great.. so say i got a column called "id".. now that i have the row selected.. how do i get the value of the id column corresponding to the selected row?

Comment: I added such a script to the answer.

Comment: perfect.. i've awarded you the correct award b/c u definitely exceeded my expectations.. i'm trying to figure this one out now.. how do i now query another spreadhseet's id column for a specific value.. then make the selection go to that specific row?

Comment: In a comment, I can only outline: I'd use `.getRange(1, n, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues()` to get the values of that column (here n is its index), then flatten it from a double to single array by `.map(function(a) {return a[0]})`, then search with `indexOf` and finally `setActiveRange`.

Comment: here is a generic comment: how can i debug a google spreadsheet? i know i can debug it while the window is already open.. but i wanna debug it by using a real spreadsheet? this would make my life so much easier

Comment: also i made the last question an actual question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37613891/how-to-query-a-google-sheet-column-for-a-certain-value.. answer and i'll give you an award there as well!

Comment: If you mean notifying you of errors, [MailApp.sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body) can send a message with a dump of some variables (using `JSON.stringify`, say).

Comment: no what i mean is that i keep on outputting stuff on a dialog within the spreadsheet to test what i'm doing (see [gist](https://gist.github.com/abbood/8900cc1fcc445dee1815a6556a4d560b)) i'd much rather be able to do this by setting a breakpoint and viewing stuff on a console like how we do it with chrome web dev tools

Comment: There's a built in debugger documented here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints