# how to query a google sheet column for a certain value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Let's say i have value 10, and I got a google sheet with first column id that has many values. I would like to run a script that goes through all the values in that column, and once it finds a match, it sets the active selection on that row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script searches the first column of the active sheet for the value of 10, and sets the selection on that value if found.

```
function setActive() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var idValues = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().map(function(a) {
    return a[0];
  });
  var row = idValues.indexOf(10) + 1;
  if (row > 0) {
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(sheet.getRange(row, 1));
  }
  else {
    throw new Error('Id not found');
  }
}
```

The array idValues is being flattened before applying indexOf, since a column is returned by getValues as a double array `[[1], [2], [3]]`.

Comment: one part i don't understand.. this line `var row = idValues.indexOf(10) + 1;`.. why do you keep on adding 1?

Comment: JavaScript indices are 0-based but spreadsheet rows and columns are numbered starting with 1.

Comment: follow up question @sandwich: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616007/how-to-programmatically-open-a-new-spread-sheet-from-google-scripts