# How to programmatically open a new spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In [setActiveSpreadSheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#setactiverangerange) doc the example is very clear:

```
// The code below will make the spreadsheet with key "1234567890" the active spreadsheet
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1234567890");
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
```

however implementing that inside my Google Scripts, nothing happens at all (not even an error message).. ideas?

## update

Based on the answers below, it's clear that the above code has no effect on UI.
I tried doing this:

```
function goToEstimate(sheetId)
{
  window.open('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+sheetId);
}
```

but then I got this error:

> ReferenceError: "window" is not defined.

Is there a way to access the JavaScript global window variable from within Google Apps Scripts?

Comment: Once again: Apps Script is server side. It knows no such thing as "window" or "document".

Answer (score 5):

An Apps Script cannot make a spreadsheet appear in a client's browser, since it is a server side script.

The method `openById` returns a handle on a spreadsheet which makes it possible to manipulate with the spreadsheet from the Apps Script. This is what "to open a spreadsheet" means for a script. This action has no effect on user's interface.

The method `setActiveSpreadsheet` is pretty much useless; it only changes which spreadsheet will be returned when a script calls `getActiveSpreadsheet`.

One method that does have effect on UI is `setActiveSheet`: if it is applied to a spreadsheet that a user has opened in their browser, the method can change which tab/sheet of that spreadsheet is facing the user.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you can't just open new tab in browser and open new spreadsheet by script. That's because script can't control browsers. But you could get data from closed Spreadsheet:

```
function openSheetTest() {
  var newWs = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1234567890');
  var sheet = newWs.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  Logger.log(data);
}
```

---

There's is a class [Browser](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser) in G-sheets. And all we can for now is to make promts or MsgBoxes.